# How to use get form field error data from javascript in a thymeleaf template file

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form in a thymeleaf template in a Spring Boot application. I can display the list of errors in my HTML (a thymeleaf template) like this:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="err : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}">
        <b th:text="${err.getFieldName()}"></b> <span th:text="${err.getMessage()}"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above code works fine, as expected. However, I wanted to get the `${#fields.detailedErrors()}` part in a javascript code in the *same page*.

I tried the inline javascript POJO java object to javascript object feature in thymeleaf as follows:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var fieldErrors = [[${#fields.detailedErrors()}]];
</script>
```

The inline javascript tag is inside the same page as the above HTML template, but the later doesn't work. The HTML generated by thymeleaf for the javascript tag is:

```
<script>
    var fieldErrors = [];
</script>
```

Meanwhile the HTML generated for the first div works fine as:

```
<ul>
    <li><b>name</b> <span>may not be empty</span></li>
    <li><b>uri</b> <span>may not be empty</span></li>
</ul>
```

In short, my question is, how do I get the `#fields.detailedErrors()` value to work inside a script tag?